# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, string, exception, nullpointerexception

I'm struggling with a weird error this morning `NullPointerException`

```
String a,b;

a = this.getA();
b = this.getB();

if(a == null || a.equals(""))
    a = "unknown a";
if(b == null || b.equals(""))
    b = "unknown b";

System.out.println("a = " + a + " & " + "b = " b);
// the output is : a = a & b = unknown b

process(a,b); // The error occure here
```

At this point I get : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

What's the problem here ?!

Comment: Please post your real code, and pinpoint the line where the error is thrown. (String doesn't have a `eqauls` method.) The actual stack trace (at least the top of it) could be useful.

Comment: Where do you get a NullPointerException? What does the println message show you?  What do you see when you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Does that compile? `eqauls()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @OpenMind, [sscce.org](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You say the error occurs in process, so show us the code in process.

Comment: A NullPointerException isnt a weird error . It'd be one of the most easily understood and debuggable errors .

Comment: Yeah I'm tired as well to fix others NullPointer problems. There are only very very few situations where a null pointer exception might be a challange for an unexperienced developer.

Comment: You are talking like if you are a professional programmer

Answer (score 2):

None of these lines can produce a `NullPointerException`. I can only imagine it is in some other part of your code. In the future, please post the entire stack trace when your question is about an exception.

EDIT: OK, you indicated it's in `process()`. So why did you post this code, instead of `process()`?

Answer (score 0):

You say in your comment that b = unknown b, which means that this.getB()==null or an empty string.  I'd guess that something in your process(a,b) method is attempting to use that original b value.  If you do getB() again does it reset the value?

If you post your process(a,b) method we could check/confirm that, as it can only be speculation until we see the actual code.